# Custom sign in not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, forms-authentication

I have created so a user can register, and his info is stored in the database. I now click on the log in, and type in the user credentials, and these will be retrieved as it should. But the system doesn't know that the user is logged in, e.i.

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
    {
       userID = User.Identity.Name;  
    }
```

returns null, as the `Request.IsAuthenticated` is false.
Here is what I did to create the login:

***One***.  I added code to the Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

***Two***. I created the Login controller that validates the user:

```
[Authorize]
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private RegisterUserController member = new RegisterUserController();

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginHandlerModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (member.ValidateUser(model.userName, model.password, model.rememberUserOnThisComputer))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.userName, model.rememberUserOnThisComputer);
                return RedirectToAction("OverView", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong email or password");
            }
        }

        ViewBag.WrongCredentials = "Wrong Credentials";

        return PartialView("_Login");
    }
```

***Three***. I added a filter to the Actions that require login:

```
[Authorize]
   public PartialViewResult Software()
    {
        ViewBag.Header = "Sofware";

        return PartialView("_Software");
    }
```

Even if the user has logged in, he cannot access this Action. And if he not logged in, he doesn't get redirected to login page, I don't know why.

***Four***. I changed my code to act accordingly if the user is logged in or not. This is the code that is not working:

```
 @{
                var userID = "Guest";

                if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
                {
                    userID = User.Identity.Name;             

                    <div style="margin-left: 3px; border: solid; border-color: #006BA0;">
                        <h5 style="color: green;">Welcome @User.Identity.Name (@Ajax.ActionLink("Log out", "LogOut", "Members", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv" })) </h5>                              
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div style="margin-left: 3px; border: solid; border-color: #006BA0;">
                        <h5 style="color: green;">
                            Welcome @userID (@Ajax.ActionLink("Log in", "LoginQuery", "Members", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv" })
                            - @Ajax.ActionLink("Register", "RenderRegisterPage", "RegisterUser", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv" }))
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                }
```

Is there something I have missed. Is there more I need to add in order to make it work?

---------------------------------Update----------------------------------------

[image]

-----------------------------2nd Update------------------------

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to debug Login? Does it execute correctly? After Login execution do you have the auth cookie?

Comment: Yeah it executes as it should, I tried debug it. I'm not sure how the auth cookie should look though, I added an image. Is there anything noticable?

Comment: in Chrome Dev Tools go to Resources, then expand Cookies and select your domain (localhost probably). You should see a .ASPXAUTH cookie. Is it there?

Comment: Yes it seems correct. I have added a screenshot

Comment: If you put in Login controller a temp public ActionResult Index(){return View();} and try to get there after login are you redirected to Login/Login or you see the view (not found)?

Comment: You mean if I redirect to: return RedirectToAction("Index", this); in Login Controller? If I do this, I get redirected to the temp public ActionResult Index() that you suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72687/discussion-between-alberto-and-user1960836).

Comment: check chat for private info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you used (I guess) VS2013 MVC5 WebApplication template, which leverages on Identity 2.0 for authentication, authorization and identity management.

In web.config there is this section:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

That's the reason why Forms Authentication does not process your HTTP requests.

If you delete the remove instruction the application will work as expected.

Otherwise you can get rid of Forms Authentication and learn how to work with Identity ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics) the best starting point IMO).